# AWS HTTP API Gateway + Lambda ( Node/express) 503 Service unavailable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**I don't have much knowledge in AWS**

I have following setup,

```
const express = require("express");
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    res.setHeader('Keep-Alive', 'timeout=30');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(`api-end-point/user`, userRoute);
....

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "lambda") {

    PORT = process.env.PORT || 7000;
    const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`node-express server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on ${PORT}`);
    });
    server.timeout = 0;

}else {

    module.exports.handler = serverless(app);

}
```

**user.controller.js**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const Base64 = require("crypto-js/enc-base64");
const config = require("../core/config/config.json");

...
...

async getUser(token, cb) {
        var params = {
            AccessToken: token /* required */
        };

        try {
            this.cognitoIdentity.getUser(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) cb(err); // an error occurred
                else cb(null, data); // successful response
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        }
}
```

And of course, I have **cognito user pool** from where I get the requested user information using above `getUser` by passing Authorization token (after login).

---

**Local Environment**

When I run this and all other APIs, believe me I haven't received any error single time and all APIs work just fine without any problem.

**API Gateway + Lambda Enviornment**

Problem happens when this code goes to Lambda function.

API gateway routes are configure as `/ANY, /{proxy+}`

Also, CORS setting is as below,

[image]

And the entire code goes to **LAMBDA** function and **lambda** is associated with **API gateway**.

---

When I hit `API gateway + Lambda (+ congnito)` to get **user information**. It works fine. Most of the time, it works but there are instances where it fails and returns (all of sudden)

> 503 Service Unavailable

***Now, I really have no idea what is going wrong***.

---

**TIMEOUT**

API gateway timeout is set to default which is **30 seconds**.

Lambda timeout is set to **10 MINUTS**. (I just increased lambda timeout to try something)

---

1. **BUT THIS ISSUE KEEPS OCCURING**
2. **Sometime (NOT Every time) I get CORS issue (out of no where and all of sudden)**
3. **Is there any way I can increase `API gateway` timeout**

What should I real do to make work every time ?

**NOTE:** getUser function is very straight forward. I don't think it is taking so much time to get user details from cognito user pool. something is wrong which I'm not able to figure out.

**Please please help**

Comment: Have you added CloudWatch logs?

Comment: Would be good to understand if you see the request hitting your lambda when it fails, are you able to see any cloudwatch logs on the lambda for the request when it gives a 503?

Comment: You cannot increase the API Gateway timeout, but I doubt that would help you anyway. I notice something off about your `getUser` function. If an error is caught there, the callback is never called, you just return false. Functions that take a callback should *always* either call the callback or throw an error. What if you `cb(error)` instead of returning false? My guess is that, under certain conditions, your server is not sending a response (`res.send()`, `res.json()`, etc). If you don't send a response, the request will time out.

Comment: Also the variable is named `e` yet you wrote `console.log(error);` which would cause an "error is not defined" error.

Comment: How often is your function triggered? Because there are 2 big possible reasons where 503 is that either you exceed the lambda execution time or you have reached the maximum concurrency that Lambda has set out (which is around 1k). You can reach out to AWS if you need to trigger your Lambda more often than that https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-concurrency-limit-increase/#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20maximum%20concurrency,when%20the%20increase%20is%20needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try increasing the timeout value for the API Gateway by going to the API Gateway settings in the AWS Management Console and editing the timeout value for the resource and method that corresponds to the Lambda function you are invoking. The default timeout for an API Gateway is under a minute, which might not be enough time for the Lambda function to complete and return a response.

Comment: This is not clear. Be more specific or just help with the screen shots...

Comment: You can not increase the API gateway timeout unfortunately. Because the 29 second timeout is a hard limit that AWS set on itself

Comment: You can verify what I said here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: I said I'm not able to understand your answer. Could you be more specific or provide more insight on how to do it (with some screen shots) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1:**

Seeing your code, I suspect that you are using `serverless` framework. If your code is running normal when you `invoke` locally, I would suggest you to try and reserve your concurrency for this function (or ask AWS to increase your account limit).[image]

You can find it in the `Concurrency` tabs and I would suggest you to reserve some concurrency resource for your function. Even though your account has a 1000 concurrency limit, if you are logging to your AWS client account using IAM or deploy on a shared resources, the capacity pools might be shared. I would suggest to check on that as well.

Since Lambda usually return `503` when:

> The number of function executions exceeded one of the quotas (formerly known as limits) that Lambda sets to throttle executions in an AWS Region (concurrent executions or invocation frequency).

or when

> The function exceeded the Lambda function timeout quota.

You can read it more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-503-lambda-limit-execeeded-error.html)

But if the worst case scenario happen, which means your account concurrency limit is hit, you would need to ask AWS support for raising your total allowed concurrency. Which involves going the [Service Quotas dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home).For a more detailed guide, you can refer to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-concurrency-limit-increase/)

**Answer to question 2:**

Would be hard to answer without knowing more on what path got `CORS` or all of your part just got `CORS`. If it's all part got `CORS` it could be due to your `OPTIONS` requests not having any response due to your server did not run (Because it hits concurrency limit or something). If concurrency is really the problem you have, this should resolve itself out.

**Answer to question 3:**

You can't raise APIGateway timeout limit unfortunately, it is fixed at 29 seconds and AWS does not allow you to change it[image]

You can read more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html)